# How to set up Ubiquiti Bullet M2 on boat or RV to connect to various WiFi hotspots across the marina or RV park?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

As the title states, I have a [Ubiquti Bullet M2](https://store.ui.com/us/en/products/bulletm2-hp). I'm looking to use the Bullet with its large antenna to connect to WiFi hotspot when in a marina or RV park.

I'm not seeing how I can tell the Bullet to connect to these password protected WiFi hotspots. Am I doing this wrong or is this not possible with this product? If it's not possible with this product, does anyone have a solution that will work?

Internet <=> WiFi Hotspot <=> Ubiquti Bullet M2 <=> POE passthrough <=> Linksys router  <=> various personal devices

Answer (score 0):

Under "Network > Network Mode", you *probably* want to select "Router" if you want to connect more than 1 device. Make sure you have "Configuration mode: Simple" and "WAN Interface: WLAN0". Configure it like you would a normal router – set WAN to DHCP, enable NAT, enable DHCP server on LAN interface, etc. Save and apply changes before continuing to the next section.

Under "Wireless", set mode to "Station". Disable WDS mode. Make sure the "Frequency Scan List" is disabled, then select the SSID you want and enter the WPA PSK if needed. (You don't need to manually disable airMAX when in station mode; it'll use whichever protocol the AP supports.)

If the network requires login through a browser, it should be fine to do it from your PC in the normal way – in "Router" mode the network will only see the M2's MAC and IP addresses.

[image]
[image]

Bullet M2 with its large antenna might be overkill; a NanoStation Loco M2 (or something similarly shaped from other manufacturers) would usually suffice for short distances (under 1km) and might be easier to mount to a wall.